# ¿Cómo expresar "sympathy" o "condolence" en español?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, vocabulario, cortesía

Ya sé que esta pregunta es un poco general, así que voy a tratar de especificar:

Digamos que un pariente de un amigo murió. ¿Cuáles son algunas palabras/frases que yo podría usar? ¿O que escribiría en una carta?

Puedo pensar en algunos ejemplos en inglés, pero me cuesta traducirlos:

> I'm sorry for your loss
>
> Sympathy
>
> Condolences

Answer (score 13, accepted):

La expresión más frecuente es `dar el pésame`, para expresar esta acción de comunicarle a alguien que lamentas el fallecimiento de su pariente:

> Me acerqué a Luis en el funeral para **darle el pésame** por la muerte de su abuelo
>
> Luis, mi más sentido **pésame** por la muerte de tu abuelo

También se suele decir `te acompaño en el sentimiento` o incluso `mis condolencias`. Resumiendo, podrías usar o escribir en una carta

- Mi más sentido **pésame**.
- Te acompaño en el sentimiento.
- Mis **condolencias** por [...]

Puedes usar también una traducción casi directa de los que propones en la pregunta (mis condolencias / Lamento tu pérdida) pero no usamos `sympathy` (compasión, afinidad, solidaridad, simpatía) en este contexto.

Answer (score 6):

Otras opciones para expresar tus condolencias (literalmente "condolences"), tanto por escrito u oralmente serían:

- "Siento mucho tu pérdida" (la misma oración que tu expresaste "I'm sorry for your loss"),
- Decir o escribir simplemente "Lo siento mucho" (+ "Te mando mi afecto", + "Te mando un abrazo", etc.)
- Te mando mi pésame