# "Pay your respects" in Spanish

Tags: traducción, formalidad

I am looking for a good translation to the phrase "Pay your respects" in Spanish.

I haven't been able to figure out one that really conveys the meaning. These are the ones I currently came up with:

- Mostrar tu respeto
- Guardar respeto

What I don't like about them is that they imply passiveness.

Comment: Can you give some context on where and to whom you want to say this?

Comment: Here's a [related question](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/13529/5481)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've always seen it translated as «presentar los respetos (de alguien a alguien)»:

> Realizar manifestaciones de cortesía a alguien. *Presenté mis respetos a su esposa*. —[Source](http://es.thefreedictionary.com/respetos).

And, I add, can be used ironically: «vamos a presentar nuestros respetos al nuevo alumno (knuckles cracking)» or in a more metaphorical way: «fueron al bar a presentar sus respetos a la cerveza que les esperaba». Even in the plain sense of paying a visit: «después de presentar nuestros respetos al museo, continuamos con la visita a la ciudad».

Comment: As native speaker, I think this is the best solution as you can use it Ironically, in case of a deceased one, format situation, etc... more or less, like in English.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to what guillem mentioned, if I am correct, this phrase is also used when someone dies, and you want to say something to the person who lost the loved one. In this case, you can say:

> Dar el pésame.

Definiton of [pésame](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?key=p%C3%A9same) on RAE:

> Expresión con que se hace saber a alguien el sentimiento que se tiene
>   de su pena o aflicción.

Comment: I don't think that "dar el pésame" is always a good translation for "Pay your respects". It works in the context of a deceased one (ie. in a funeral), but you could pay your respects to someone who is alive (a important authority), or to something else. For example "mafia groups set themselves apart as a separate law ... that is, they must **pay respect** exclusively to the mafia legal order" (From Letizia Paoli's _Mafia Brotherhoods : Organized Crime, Italian Style_). Or "pay your respect to the boss". So, in this context you can't use "dar el pésame".

Comment: You are right. This is why I specified the context on the answer, since the question does not specify any.

Answer (score 0):

In Colombia the expression used is "Saludar".  "Voy a saludar a ...".  Keep in mind that "saludar" also is used to greet someone,  however in a specif context,  it's meaning goes beyond the act of greeting and extends to the act of saluting of paying respect to.